# How to calculate average mark after filtering by author name?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I can't figure out other ways to calculate the average mark of all posts belong to author. I used the aggregation in django but having problem that QuerySet has no attributes Objects.

```
def get_queryset(self) :
    queryset_list = Post.objects.all()
    query = self.request.GET.get("q")
    print(query)
    if query :
       queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(author__username=query)
    abc = self.calc_mark_avg(queryset_list)
    return abc
    return queryset_list
def calc_mark_avg(self,queryset_list) :
    author = queryset_list
    mean = author.objects.all().aggreagate(Avg('mark'))
    return mean
```

Answer (score 0):

`queryset_list` is filtered queryset, hence it does not have manager (that is objects).

You can directly apply aggreagation on queryset

```
def calc_mark_avg(self,queryset_list) :
    return queryset_list.aggreagate(Avg('mark'))
```

For more read info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses